# Callback on immutable.js .set

Tags: javascript, immutable.js

I'm new to immutable.js and I was wondering if I could set up an immutable object to run a callback function when `.set` is called on a specific property.

For example:

```
const { Map } = require('immutable');
const map = Map();
map.onChange('value', () => {
  /*
    Do some things when map.set('value', 'some new value') is called.
  */
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't know if there's an easier way of doing this, but you can achieve what you want using proxies.

```
var handler = {
  get: function(target, property, receiver) {
    if (property === 'set') {
      const origMethod = target[property];
      return function(...args) {
        // Add your callback in here
        console.log(`set was called with ${args}`)
        return origMethod.apply(this, args);
      };
    }
    return target[property]
  }
};

var map1 = new Proxy (Immutable.Map({'b': 123}), handler)
var map2 = map1.set('b', 50);
console.log(map1.get('b')); // 123
console.log(map2.get('b')); // 50
```

http://jsfiddle.net/3bgub8r2/3/